# Theme path of Wordpress inside javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have two files:

## abc.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:ABC Template
*/
?>
<div id="div-image" class="div-child"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/Images/Loading.gif" id="load" /> </div> 
 <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/alphawords.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

## xyz.js

```
document.getElementById("load").src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/Images/pic.png";
```

`xyz.js` is included properly, but image is not being loaded through the JS. How can I get the image to load properly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a trigger for your JS. You can test that the script is actually running by adding a quick console, such as

`console.log('xyz.js is running');`

Once you're sure your JS is running, you can add a trigger. If you're already loading jQuery, it has an easy `.ready()` function to use, but if not, there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/vanilla-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-whe).

It's also best practice to enqueue your JavaScript, instead of adding `<script>` tags directly. See [wp_enqueue_script().](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) You may want to do this before adding your console and before adding the trigger, as really enqueueing is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use PHP inside a JS file, which won't work. Instead, you'll need to pass the dynamic path to your JS file from PHP using `wp_localize_script()` which can be used on enqueued and registered scripts like this:

```
function custom_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-xyz', // Handle
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/xyz.js',
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'custom-xyz', // Handle
        'my_object', // Object variable name
        array('theme_dir' => get_template_directory_uri()) // Properties and values
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_script');
```

And then in the xyz.js file, the `my_object` is an object variable available to you.

```
document.getElementById("load").src = my_object.theme_dir + "/Images/pic.png";
```